# Proper property semantics for forwarding to a copied property in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiview, properties

Let's assume there is a `UIView` that contains a `UILabel` internally.

The `UIView`'s public interface is as follows in it's `.h`:

```
@interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;

@end
```

and privately within it's `.m`:

```
@interface MyView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel coolLabel;

@end
```

with the implementation in it's `.m`:

```
@implementation

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    self.coolLabel.text = text;
}

- (NSString *)text
{
   return self.coolLabel.text;
}

@end
```

Looking at the public interface I declare `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text` with a `copy` because the text is copied by the `coolLabel` internally. However, I'm not sure if this is correct.

Should the declaration be `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *text` with an `assign` instead because my class isn't specifically performing the memory management? Or is my current interface declared correctly?

FYI, everything assumes **ARC**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `text` property should be `copy` because ultimately its value is being copied by the label.

The `property` definition is like a contract. You are telling users of the property how the value will be treated. Since the label copies the text, you should indicate your property is being copied.

Comment: Does this in any way change how ARC operates?